# Passing data between forms using PHP and jQuery : Chained select box

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have 2 inputs forms - Subject and Unit. Units come inside subjects.
Example:

- Subject - English, Math
- Unit - Nouns, Tenses, Algebra, Geometry

The units table in the DB has a foreign key from the subjects table.

I am making an admin panel which displays me all the content within a subject + unit combination. My options in the subject dropdown are fetched from the DB. For a given value of a subject, I can do the same for the unit dropdown as well.

Passing the data is where I am stuck. I am using the $_GET to take the value from the subject dropdown and passing it on the unit dropdown. The unit dropdown shows the right values but that is removing the value from the subject dropdown.

```
    $("select.subject").change(function(){
       var selsub = $(".subject option:selected").val();
       var see = $(".subject option:selected").text();
       window.location.href = "index.php?" + "&selsub="+ selsub + "&name=" + see;   
   });
```

The JS variables get removed because the page is reloading.

I need a quick jquery way in which I can save this value. Not a pro at PHP, haven't worked with AJAX as such, but any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $("select.subject").change(function(){
   var selsub = $(".subject option:selected").val();
   var see = $(".subject option:selected").text();
   $.ajax({
     url :"index.php",
     type:"GET",
     data: "selsub="+ selsub + "&name=" + see,
     success:function(response){
       //Do success operation
     }
   }); 
});
```

Comment: What will be the success operation in this case? What I want to do are 2 things 1) Let the value of the selected subject exist + the listing of the unit dropdown change based on my subject selection

Comment: If you want **chained select box** , check out this .[http://www.blueicestudios.com/chained-select-boxes-using-php-mysql-ajax/](http://www.blueicestudios.com/chained-select-boxes-using-php-mysql-ajax/)

Comment: I am looking for a chained select box - that's correct. Is there an easy way to implement it? Paying $50 isn't an option